# Image size defaulting to 100% in css?

Tags: image, wordpress, css

Anyone ever dealt with every time you upload a photo in the cms that the image holds its full uploaded size no matter if you re-size it or not.

It is like there is a hidden min-width:100% somewhere that I can't get rid of. I have to manually set a max width to every photo I put on my site. I have to get rid of this.

help!!!!

Comment: Have you tried to use something like Firebug to see if there are any CSS rules applying?  Also, if it's a custom theme, maybe the standard image class values haven't been set up in the theme's css?

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting with Wordpress' page/post entry, click the image in the said entry and then click the edit image icon that comes up at the top-left corner within the image. This will bring up the image's properties set by Wordpress and will allow you adjust the size among others.